# Finding Magnetic Field in loop of wire in semicircle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

This is the problem I'm working on:

A loop of wire has the shape of two concentric semicircles connected by two radial segments (See figure). The loop carries a current $I = 280.00 A$. Find the magnetic field at point $P$. 
($R = 21.00 cm$)

[image]

So I the magnetic field due to an arc to be $B = (\mu_0I/2\pi)(\alpha/r)$, which, if we take $r = 2R$ for the top arc and $r = R$ for the bottom arc, and $\alpha = \pi/2$ for both arcs, we get:

$B=(\mu_0I/4)(1/2R - 1/R)$

The answer I'm getting using this equation is wrong. Where is my mistake? Am I going down the correct path for this question?

Comment: Perhaps $\alpha$ should be $\pi$?  (I haven't looked closely at this.)

Comment: I think @garyp is right - you have 180 degrees, so $\pi$.

Comment: So then the equation would change to $B = (\mu_0I/2)(1/2R - 1/R)$ ? If I have my math right.

Comment: I think your starting equation is wrong, too.

Comment: What should it be instead?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this: calculate the field due to a complete "outer" loop (radius $2R$). Subtract from it the field due to the complete "inner" loop (radius $R$).

Divide the number you get by two (because you only have half a loop). It makes the whole process a little more transparent - easier to follow.

Finally you need to take a look at the diagram to decide what the direction of the net flux should be. The inner loop has a clockwise current and (being closer) should give the strongest field. Looks to me like that means the field is *into* the page. Make sure that your sign matches.